# Change stock button image color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, accessoryview

I would like to change the color of the default accessory disclosure view... the ( > ) in a table cell. I cant seem to do it in code so is it possible to get apple's image and adjust the colors in gimp?

Comment: You can add custom image to the table view content image to give a similar effect. I can write the code to do in case you are open to experimenting like this.

Comment: @Praveen-S Thanks Praveen, but I have been able to do that with certain views (I changed the accessory view to a calendar button using something like cell.accessoryView). The thing is I have nothing wrong with the default button image, but after changing the tint of my navigation bar the blue color stands out of place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the default accessory disclosure view , But you could consider implementation  `Custom Accessory View` in `UITableView`.

Follow the below blog post.

[Implement a Custom Accessory View For UITableView in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

Comment: good resource but I was looking for the location of the stock image so I could just change the color. What I actually did was take a screen capture of the iPhone simulator's button and edit it, but my color manipulation skills in gimp didn't quite get me there. maybe making one from scratch will get me what I want